Enforce conditional constraints with OR-Tools for a routing problem
I have a routing problem where I want a set of waypoints to be done one after another without anything in between as long as one has been started in the set.
For example:

Waypoints (A, B, C, D, E)
A, C, E must be done together as long as one is started

Which gives us:

The driver goes to B, then A, then they must do C and E so (B, A, C,
E, D) or (B, A, E, C, D) but (B, A, D, E, C) is wrong.

I would have wanted to use something like OnlyEnforceIf for a constraint but I can see it does not work with the routing solver.
Does anyone have an idea of a solution? I assume I need conditional constraints but cannot work out a way of doing it.

if you keep a count dimension for the number of locations visited and add constraints that
count of A should be within +/- 2 of count of E
count of A should be within +/- 2 of count of C
... similarly total 6(n * (n-1), n=3) constraints
it should suffice, right ?

Sorry, cannot write a comment, so I post it as (incomplete) answer:
Should be possible to check .ActiveVar(index)
and to set .NextVar(index)
https://or-tools.github.io/docs/pdoc/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.html#RoutingModel.NextVar
And .OnlyEnforeIf() can alternatively also be expressed as Boolean or LP formulation.
